# publishProgress not calling onProgressUpdate

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that uses polls a queue to see if a new object has arrived.  When it detects the new object, I have it collect information as a string and then publishProgress(info).  In onProgressUpdate it adds the string to a list.  The problem that I am encountering is that the program never enters onProgressUpdate.  I stepped through it in the debugger and I see it call publishProgress, however it never enters onProgress update.  looks something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        messageQueue.add(displayName + " : " + values[0]);   //I have a breakpoint here that the program never hits.
        ((BaseAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (true) {
            Packet p = pc.pollResult();
            if(p != null){
                String body = ((Message) p).getBody();   //I have a breakpoint here that the program hits only when a new object is in the queue
                publishProgress(body);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Weird, have you tried changing String body to a String array instead?

Comment: Sorry about this being somewhat of a waste of a post, I think my emulator was just tripping over itself.  I restarted eclipse and everything was working just fine...

Comment: I was going to recommend that but figured it might get downvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue where it wasnt getting called but I just noticed I put the in the wrong class. It of course it suppose to be inside the AsyncTask block but instaead I had created it outside  of that block

Answer (score 1):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

**Threading rules**

There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class to work properly:

```
execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

**This may help someone with genuine error**

Notice the second argument in AsyncTask refers to Progress

```
AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

Make sure your datatype matches.

```
AsyncTask<URL, String, Long>{

    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
    return long;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {}


    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {}

}
```